# Presto SQL full outer join

Tags: sql, presto

I've got a full join that isn't working like how I expected it to.

I'm joining on 4 columns. However, one of the columns has some blank values, causing some numbers to come up[ unjoint. When I take this column out, the query works. However, I have to have this certain column for the report as it's how we are reporting on the numbers.

Query in question: (the column that doesn't work is the OM.line_item_id)

```
SELECT DBM.dated, DBM.line_item, DBM.line_item_id, DBM.insertion_order, DBM.insertion_order_id, DBM.device_type, DBM.market, DBM.impressions, DBM.clicks, DBM.amount_spent_EUR, OM.orders, OM.revenue, OM.device

FROM
(

SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(DATE_PARSE(date,'%Y/%m/%d'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS dated, line_item, line_item_id, insertion_order, insertion_order_id, device_type, trim(SPLIT_PART(insertion_order,'|',3)) AS market, cast(impressions as double) as impressions, cast(clicks as double) as clicks, CAST(media_cost_advertiser_currency AS DOUBLE)*1.15 AS amount_spent_EUR


FROM ralph_lauren_google_sheet_dbm_data  

WHERE dated >= '2019-03-31'
AND dated <= {{days_ago 1}}

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

)DBM 

FULL outer JOIN

( 

SELECT dated, line_item_id, device, market, sum(orders) as orders, sum(revenue)+sum(shipping_revenue)-sum(coupon_discount) as revenue

FROM

(
select
dated,
utm_content_v21 as line_item_id,
order_currency_code_v33_evar33,
case lower(mobile_device_type)
when 'other' then 'Desktop'
when 'tablet' then 'Tablet'
when 'mobile phone' then 'Smart Phone'
        else 'Other'
        End as device,
case geosegmentation_countries
    when 'united kingdom' then 'UK'
    when 'germany' then 'DE'
    when 'france' then 'FR'
    when 'italy' then 'IT'
    when 'spain' then 'ES'
    else 'other'
    end as market,
sum(cast(orders as bigint))as orders,

            case
    WHEN lower(order_currency_code_v33_evar33) LIKE '%gbp%' THEN sum(TRY_CAST(revenue AS DOUBLE)*1.15)
    ELSE Sum(TRY_CAST(revenue AS DOUBLE)*1)
    END as revenue, 

    CASE
   WHEN lower(order_currency_code_v33_evar33) LIKE '%gbp%' THEN sum(TRY_CAST(order_level_shipping_revenue_e62_event62 AS DOUBLE)*1.15)
   ELSE sum(TRY_CAST(order_level_shipping_revenue_e62_event62 AS DOUBLE)*1)
   END as shipping_revenue,

CASE
    WHEN lower(order_currency_code_v33_evar33) LIKE '%gbp%' THEN sum(TRY_CAST(order_level_coupon_discount_e77_event77 AS DOUBLE)*1.15)  
    ELSE sum(TRY_CAST(order_level_coupon_discount_e77_event77 AS DOUBLE)*1)
    END as coupon_discount

from ralph_lauren_ftp_all_eu_markets_ltc  

WHERE dated >= '2019-03-31'
AND dated <= {{days_ago 1}}

and last_touch_channel like 'Retargeting' 

and lower(utm_medium_v21) not like '%fbig%'

and cast(orders as bigint) > 0


group by
1,2,3,4,5
)

GROUP BY 

1,2,3 ,4-- revenue numbers are getting duplicated for some reason

)OM

ON

DBM.dated = OM.dated AND DBM.line_item_id = OM.line_item_id and DBM.device_type = OM.device AND DBM.market = OM.market
```

wouldn't a full outer join allow me to join up numbers if they have the other three columns being joint up?

thanks

Comment: Aki, why don't you put null and empty values filter for that column? That should resolve the issue.

Comment: would that be like a case statement, and add a case when there is a null value?

Comment: I think simple where clause should do the work there.